# How to bind to AJAX complete event in regard to styling the AJAX button submit throbber

Tags: forms, ajax

With this I can bind to the AJAX button submit event:

`Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend = function (xmlhttprequest, options) {
...
}`

My question, how to bind to the opposite (i.e. when AJAX button submit finishes)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `success` function. [You can refer this for its usage](https://www.drupal.org/node/1028410#comment-7780409).

```
/**
 * Handler for the form redirection completion.
 */
Drupal.ajax.prototype.success = function (response, status) {
  ...
}
```